# Get different accuracy on the same evaluating dataset after loading saved model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I just simply use MNIST dataset to implement a simple ML application. My code is

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=loss_fn,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)

print('Before saving')
model.evaluate(x_test,  y_test, verbose=2)

model.save('model.h5')

# load model again
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
# evaluate on the same data
print('After loading')
loaded_model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)
```

The accuracies on the same dataset are different after loading
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42045

Compile the model with `metrics='sparse_categorical_accuracy'` instead of just `'accuracy'`.